# Unexpected TIMESTAMP format in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, timestamp, sql-insert

I'm trying to populate my `time` column which is a `TIMESTAMP` datatype with an `INSERT` command from my Python script. This is my current code for the insert:

```
usercount= ("INSERT INTO UserNum(Amount, Network) \
VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % \
(num_user, nets_id["name"]))
```

I haven't included to insert a `TIMESTAMP` value as I believe this gets automatically generated upon `INSERT`

But when I look at the UserNum table the time column is populated by values such as `AAAAAAAAE5U=` is there something I'm doing wrong?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: `print(num_user)` and `print(nets_id["name"])` <-- what is the output of this?

Comment: print(num_user) is an int which can change on every execution this time it was "144" and print(nets_id["name"]) is just the string for the network name for example "main network" @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The timestamp datatype in sql server has no relationship to time or date. It is more properly known as rowversion and the value of that column is maintained by the database engine. Why are you concerned about the value stored in this column? It serves a single purpose - to know if a row has been changed in some fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make your arguments strings. Python handles it.
Try this:

```
usercount = "INSERT INTO UserNum(Amount, Network) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (num_user, nets_id["name"])
```

but be sure that they are of the same type as in your DB.